# Python : line executed two times on output

Tags: python

i'm making a dictionary program that take definition of a word from a json file and output it to the console.
There is the output:
[image: console output]

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))


def get_matches(w):
    return get_close_matches(w, data, 3, 0.8)


def get_definitions(w):

    if w in data:
        return data[w]

    else:
        suggested_words = get_matches(w)

        if len(suggested_words) != 0 and w in data:
            return get_matches(w)

        elif len(suggested_words) != 0 and w != data:
            new_input = input("Please check again : ")

            while 1:
                suggested_words = get_matches(new_input)
                if new_input in data or len(suggested_words) == 0 or new_input == 'q':
                    break
                print("Did you mean %s instead ?" % suggested_words)
                new_input = input("Please check again (enter q to quit) : ")

            if new_input in data and len(suggested_words) != 0:
                return data[new_input]

            elif new_input == 'q' and len(suggested_words) != 0:
                return "You have quit."

            else:
                return "This word doesn't exist in the dictionary."

        else:
            return "This word doesn't exist in the dictionary."


word = input("Please enter a word : ").lower()
output = get_definitions(word)

if isinstance(output, list,):
    for i in output:
        print(i)

else:
    print(get_definitions(word))
```

The code is working but i have a little problem when i want to type 'q' to quit the program i got another input cheeking for 'q' i don't know what this happening it should quit when i type 'q' at the first time.
Thanks for helping

Comment: I want to mention that you can include a picture in your question

Comment: You have problem with the logic; You are testing `if w in data` then if it is not  (`else` block), you check again `if len(suggested_words) != 0 and w in data`, this condition will never occur, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this part of the code:

```
    if len(suggested_words) != 0 and w in data:
        return get_matches(w)

    elif len(suggested_words) != 0 and w != data:
        new_input = input("Please check again : ")
```

The first if never returns True because in this branch 2 is never in data.

You should have:

```
    if len(suggested_words) != 0:
        return get_matches(w)
        new_input = input("Please check again : ")
```